# How to insert line of pattern match in the next line?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a below set of lines in a file, I would like to insert a new line after outputs with the same content of the line but instead of `uat_reset_fwd_outputs` it should be `Test_sample_data`

```
[serverClass:UAT_SAI_Forwarder:app:uat_sai_inputs]  
[serverClass:UAT_SAI_Forwarder:app:uat_reset_fwd_outputs]  

[serverClass:UAT_TEST_Forwarder:app:uat_test_inputs]  
[serverClass:UAT_TEST_Forwarder:app:uat_reset_fwd_outputs]  

The output should look like below:  

[serverClass:UAT_SAI_Forwarder:app:uat_sai_inputs]  
[serverClass:UAT_SAI_Forwarder:app:uat_reset_fwd_outputs]  
[serverClass:UAT_SAI_Forwarder:app:Test_sample_data]  

[serverClass:UAT_TEST_Forwarder:app:uat_test_inputs]  
[serverClass:UAT_TEST_Forwarder:app:uat_reset_fwd_outputs]  
[serverClass:UAT_TEST_Forwarder:app:Test_sample_data]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
perl -lne 'print;if(/uat_reset_fwd_outputs/){s/uat_reset_fwd_outputs/Test_sample_data/;print $_}' your_file
```

If you want to do in place replacement, use below:

```
perl -i -lne 'print;if(/uat_reset_fwd_outputs/){s/uat_reset_fwd_outputs/Test_sample_data/;print $_}' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(^.*\):.*outputs.*$/\0\n\1:Test_sample_data]/g' file.txt
```

This command matches any line containing the string "outputs", captures the first part of the line (in \1) and appends "Test_sample_data" to it.

Comment: This is replacing the string match pattern "outputs" to Test_sample_data". But i need the output should be appended in the next line of the match pattern.

Output should look like below:

[serverClass:UAT_TEST_Forwarder:app:uat_test_inputs]  
[serverClass:UAT_TEST_Forwarder:app:uat_reset_fwd_outputs]  
[serverClass:UAT_TEST_Forwarder:app:Test_sample_data]

Comment: It's not replacing the outputs line. It's appending a new line after it. That's what `\0\n\1` does. Have you tried running my command?

Comment: yes, i did try and the output as follows:

sed 's/\(^.*\):.*outputs.*$/\0\n\1:Test_sample_data]/g' pesting 

[serverClass:UAT_SAI_Forwarder:app:uat_sai_inputs]
0n[serverClass:UAT_SAI_Forwarder:app:Test_sample_data]

[serverClass:UAT_TEST_Forwarder:app:uat_test_inputs]
0n[serverClass:UAT_TEST_Forwarder:app:Test_sample_data]

Comment: Must be your sed version. It works fine for me on `GNU sed version 4.2.1`. What is your `sed --version`?

Comment: Mine is not GNU Version. I use Mac book. Can you help resolving this on mac?

Comment: Can you help resolving this on Mac OS. I tried resolving this but i did not find any way to solve it, When i run the command you have given the output is not getting appended in the next line instead its printing 0n. Please check below:

[serverClass:UAT_SAI_Forwarder:app:uat_sai_inputs]
0n[serverClass:UAT_SAI_Forwarder:app:Test_sample_data]

[serverClass:UAT_TEST_Forwarder:app:uat_test_inputs]
0n[serverClass:UAT_TEST_Forwarder:app:Test_sample_data]

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sed '/:[^:]*outputs] *$/{h;s//:Test_sample_data]/;x;G}' file
```

**Update :**

The new line will be appended to any line ending with `outputs]`.

Comment: It did not work. There is small correction in the question. uat_reset_fwd_outputs is not constant. for an instance i gave uat_reset_fwd_outputs, there are plenty of lines in the file which ends with outputs. Also, im wanna convey mine is not GNU version. I use Mac.